# How do you patch a kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, patch

I got diff text from [lkml](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/5/30/513) how do I patch it into a kernel source? I am using debian

Comment: Short answer: you patch source code with the `patch` utility. But once you've done that, configuring and compiling the kernel correctly is a whole other question, and a pretty broad one at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kernel.org has some excellent documentation on [Applying Patches to the Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/applying-patches.txt).

Essentially, you use the [patch command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch). Once you have acquired the patch (here called `patchfile`), place it in your build directory and then issue the command:

```
patch -p <num> < patchfile
```

where <num> is the number of leading slashes to remove from the filenames contained in the patch to be applied.

So, assuming your patchfile is in the top-level directory of your kernel source, you can apply it with:

```
patch -p1 -i patchfile
```

patch also has a helpful `--dry-run` option which will print out a list of what the command will do, without making any changes to your files: allowing you to fine tune any adjustments prior to committing them.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I didn't look hard enough. Sorry for the duplicate!